# After installing curl extension php stop working

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, curl

on my working ubuntu 12.04 server i installed the curl extension for php with the commands:

```
apt-get install curl
apt-get install php5-curl
service apache2 restart
```

after doing that php stop working
if I request some .php page, firefox attempts to download the file instead of running the script

after some research i found that under the directory `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` missing the links to the files:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load
```

so I ran the command `a2enmod php5` and links have been created
but when i lunch `service apache2 restart` it fails
under `/var/log/apache2/error.log` i found some lines like:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Stratup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

for various estensions.
i've verified that the directory `/usr/lib/php5/20100525/` doesn't exist anymore
but i found the directory `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/` that contains the .so files

I also saw that the directory `/etc/php5/conf.d` is empty, there are no links, but all .ini files are under `/etc/php5/mods-available`

My questions are:
why the update has created all these problems?
how can i fix that? the solutions can be change the reference from `/usr/lib/php5/20100525/` to `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/`? where i can do that?

thanks for any help and sorry for my english

**UPDATE**
I have created the link as suggested by seb

```
ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ /usr/lib/php5/20100525
```

but when i restart apache it fails with error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache/apache2.conf:
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load:
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server:
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

can a reinstallation of php solve the problem?
if yes how can i do that?
thanks again

**UPDATE**
after a few more unsuccessful attempt I restored the virtual machine from a snapshotand I solved the problem using aptitude.

```
aptitude install php5-curl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3{a} libjson-c2{a} php5-curl php5-json{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php5-common 
1 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
Need to get 722 kB of archives. After unpacking 820 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Dipende: php5-common (= 5.4.12-2~precise+1) but 5.5.3+dfsg 1+debphp.org~precise+2 is to be installed.
 php5-gd : Dipende: php5-common (= 5.4.12-2~precise+1) but 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 is to be installed.
 php5-mcrypt : Dipende: php5-common (= 5.4.12-2~precise+1) but 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 is to be installed.
 php5-mysql : Dipende: php5-common (= 5.4.12-2~precise+1) but 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 is to be installed.
 php5-cli : Dipende: php5-common (= 5.4.12-2~precise+1) but 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:              
1)     libapache2-mod-php5                       
2)     php5                                      
3)     php5-cli                                  
4)     php5-gd                                   
5)     php5-mcrypt                               
6)     php5-mysql                                
7)     phpmyadmin                                

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
8)     libapache2-mod-php5 recommends php5-cli   


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

This first solution I answered No
The second proposed solution is

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
      Remove the following packages:
1)      apache2.2-bin 
2)      apache2.2-common 

      Install the following packages:
3)      apache2-bin [2.4.6-2~precise+1 (precise)] 
4)      apache2-data [2.4.6-2~precise+1 (precise)]
5)      libgd3 [2.1.0-2~precise+1 (precise)]
6)      liblua5.1-0 [5.1.4-12ubuntu1 (precise)]
7)      libtiff4 [3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5 (precise-security, precise-updates)]
8)      libvpx1 [1.0.0-1 (precise)]
9)      php5-readline [5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (precise)]

      Upgrade the following packages:
10)     apache2 [2.2.22-1ubuntu1.2 (now) -> 2.4.6-2~precise+1 (precise)]
11)     apache2-mpm-itk [2.2.22-1ubuntu1.2 (now) -> 2.4.6-2~precise+1 (precise)]
12)     libapache2-mod-php5 [5.4.12-2~precise+1 (now) -> 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (precise)]
13)     libaprutil1 [1.3.12+dfsg-3 (now, precise) -> 1.5.2-1~precise+1 (precise)]
14)     libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 [1.3.12+dfsg-3 (now, precise) -> 1.5.2-1~precise+1 (precise)]
15)     libaprutil1-ldap [1.3.12+dfsg-3 (now, precise) -> 1.5.2-1~precise+1 (precise)]
16)     php5-cli [5.4.12-2~precise+1 (now) -> 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (precise)]
17)     php5-gd [5.4.12-2~precise+1 (now) -> 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (precise)]
18)     php5-mcrypt [5.4.12-2~precise+1 (now) -> 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (precise)]
19)     php5-mysql [5.4.12-2~precise+1 (now) -> 5.5.3+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (precise)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

I accepted this second solution and the installation is successful, I only had to adjust the configurations of the virtual hosts for apache 2.4

Comment: tried to install pdo also and do an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont now why it happened but you could just link /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ to /usr/lib/php5/20100525/

```
ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ /usr/lib/php5/20100525/
```

So you dont need to change all config files.

Update:

You can reinstall php with

```
apt-get purge php5
apt-get install php5
```

I think a better package manager than `apt-get` is `aptitude`.

Comment: I have marked your answer as accepted because the suggestion of using aptitude let me to the solution, many thanks